# Converting several active records into single array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've got an app where I have users who get assigned to clients. There are multiple projects that belong to each of those clients client. I'm trying to create a drop down of projects that contain all the projects that the user is responsible for. To do this, I have created the instance variable @project, and @client stores each client the user is assigned to. What I've done from here is loop through client and searched the Project DB for where client = @client and add that to @project:

```
@client.each do |myprojects|
   @project << Project.where(client: myprojects.client_name)
end
```

This results in @projects storing Activerecord_Relations which isn't what I was hoping for. Is there a way to simply store all the data as just one array? That way I can print out my drop down list by using @project.project_name.

Comment: use `map` or `pluck` method

Comment: `Project.where(client: myprojects.client_name).pluck(&:project)` try this

Answer (score 0):

Use the syntax

```
Model.where(attribute: array_of_attributes)
```

So for ur case

```
@client.each do |myprojects|
    names << myprojects.client_name
end
@project = Project.where(client: names)
```

I dont really like handling arrays due to various reasons, but to convert it to array, u can do this

```
@project.to_a
```

Btw I think ur database can be better improved. A project should `belong_to` a client, so that getting 'all the projects that the user is responsible for' is just

```
@client.projects.pluck(:project_name)
```